# Need advice.. dynamic td tr

Tags: coldfusion

Hi am doing dynamic TR and TD in coldfusion, but apparently i am trying this kind of screen. here is my try with colfusion

```
<cfif variables.newrow EQ true>
   <tr align="center">
  </cfif>
  <cfoutput query="gResults">
  <cfquery datasource="#request.dsn#" name="nextqueries">
        Query
  </cfquery>
    <td height="30" valign="middle"><strong>
    <a href="viewdir.cfm?catID=#val(pic_id)#
<cfif isDefined('url.l') and url.l neq ''>&l=#url.l#</cfif>">
    #pic_cat_name#</a></strong><br>
      <cfloop query="nextqueries">
      <cfquery datasource="#request.dsn#" name="showanother">
        select * from 
        mytable as grlist
      where pic_cid = 
      <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#Trim(nextqueries.pic_id)">
      </cfquery>
      &raquo;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="viewdir.cfm?catID=#val(pic_id)#
   <cfif isDefined('url.l') and url.l neq ''>&l=#url.l#</cfif>">#pic_cat_name#
      </a> </cfloop></td>
    <cfif gResults.currentRow MOD 4 EQ 0>
        </tr>
      <cfset variables.newrow = true>
      <cfelse>
      <cfset variables.newrow = false>
    </cfif>
  </cfoutput>
```

trying to do like this:

http://screencast.com/t/oso4jkhBm3

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of potential improvements, but this answer will only deal with table rows.  You start with:

```
<cfif variables.newrow EQ true>
<tr align="center">
</cfif>
```

Now I'm going to look for the closing tag.  The only one I see is here:

```
<cfif gResults.currentRow MOD 4 EQ 0></tr></cfif>
```

and that line is inside a query loop.  What this means is that you might have more than one closing tag, or you might not have any.  You need exactly one.   To solve this specific problem, you have to do this:

```
<cfif variables.newrow EQ true>
<tr align="center">
code to populate this table row
</cfif>
```

When you get that part sorted out, we can look at what goes into the details.

Comment: Rule number 1 - take nothing seriously.  Ask your question and focus on answers and suggestions.  I get negative votes from time to time, but nobody on Stackoverflow can take away our birthdays.

Comment: 'why my question marked negative'  - what was the question?  You said 'Need advice'  - on what exactly?  What was wrong, what are you trying to do?  None of this is clear from your 'question'

Answer (score 1):

To get data to display in an html table from top to bottom then left to right like in the image linked in your question, you can do something similar to the following.

```
<!--- Get query results --->
<cfset arrayOFValues = arraynew(1)>
<cfset queryResults = querynew("Col1,Col2,Col3")>
<!--- Fill query with example data --->
<cfloop from="1" to="25" index="i">
    <cfset queryaddrow(queryResults)>
    <cfset querySetCell(queryResults, "Col1", "Col1 Row " & i)>
    <cfset querySetCell(queryResults, "Col2", "Col1 Row " & i)>
    <cfset querySetCell(queryResults, "Col3", "Col1 Row " & i)>
</cfloop>
<!--- Now have a query named queryResults with 25 rows --->
<!--- Set the number of columns and calculate the number of rows needed --->
<cfset numberOfColumns = 3>
<cfset rowsNeeded = ceiling(queryResults.recordcount / numberOfColumns)>
<cfoutput>
    <table>
        <cfloop from="1" to="#rowsNeeded#" index="curRow">
            <tr>
                <cfloop from="0" to="#numberOfColumns-1#" index="curCol">
                    <td>
                        #queryResults.Col1[(rowsNeeded * curCol) + curRow]#
                    </td>
                </cfloop>
            </tr>
        </cfloop>
    </table>
</cfoutput>
```

The first part is just creating a query result.  I then find the number of rows that is needed to display the records by dividing the number of results returned in the query by the number of columns to be displayed. The `ceiling` is required for when the result is not a whole number.

We have to loop each column record with in the row to get the desired index.  To find the required index of the field we have to take the row that’s being displayed + the column were on times the the number of rows that will be displayed.

If you know the number of columns you can hard code for them in the following manner and eliminate the inner loop.

```
<tr>
    <td>#queryResults.Col1[3 * rowsNeeded]#</td> 
    <td>#queryResults.Col1[3 + 1*rowsNeeded]#</td>
    <td>#queryResults.Col1[3 + 2*rowsNeeded]#</td>
</tr>
```